# Variable get set only if I use var_dump or echo, not with debugger breakpoint

Tags: php, codeigniter, xdebug

So I'm getting this strange behaviour from my php code.

```
public function index() {
  $interval = (int)('60');
  // echo $interval;
  // If I uncomment and put a breakpoint above, 
  // I can see the variable $interval value in my debugger.
  // But without an 'echo' or 'var_dump' statement, 
  // value is not getting set in $interval.
  die;
}
```

When I write the $interval variable to the output stream using 'echo' or 'var_dump', the $interval variable is showing properly and get set.
But if I break the execution using a debugger after interval initialisation instead of writing to the output stream variable is not getting set.

Given below are the debugger screenshots.

**This works!**

[image: This works!]

**This does not!**

[image: This does not!]

Any idea why this strange behaviour? There is no problem if I run this in a separate php file. Issue exists only inside Codeigniter instance.

**PHP Version: 7.2.8

Codeigniter: 3.1.5**

Comment: *"Any idea why this strange behaviour?"* Optimisations?.. Why bother with keeping variable if it will not be used anywhere later after initialisation? P.S. Try with OPCache disabled -- may see different behaviour.

Comment: @LazyOne I'm using codeigniter framework. index() function is the default route. This is just a portion of another function. In that function, that $interval variable is used for many purposes. Need more clarifications? I just want to know why this code is behaving like this. This is only for me to understanding how its works. btw, ill try with OPCache disabled.

Comment: *"In that function, that $interval variable is used for many purposes. Need more clarifications? "* I do not see anything like that in your code example. BTW, when I said "why bother" it was about what Xdebug/PHP does and not you. If PHP/Xdebug sees that local variable is not used later ... then no real point of keeping it... Other languages/IDE do similar stuff (e.g. Delphi debugger for sure)

Comment: I bother because I'm not able to access that variable. I need that value for inserting into a database field.

Comment: *"I bother because I'm not able to access that variable."* 1) You misunderstood what I was saying 2) The screenshots (the code) that you have showed so far tell that such optimisation makes sense. if in your **real** code it does the same .. then you must be having some error/typo in your code ... but I cannot say that for sure simply because I do not see your real code.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
function writeMsg() {
    echo "Hello world!";
}

writeMsg(); // call the function
?>
```

Comment: index() function is calling and breaking in the breakpoint. please see the screenshot.

Comment: You Should try class myClass {
    public function __toString(){
        // custom var_dump() content here then output it
    }
}

$myClass = new myClass();

echo $myClass;

Comment: see, the index function is calling already. I'm not asking about how to call that function. :) also i don’t want to output the $interval variable. i need the variable value for updating a database field.